# Google AdMob type

Tags: android, ios, admob

I saw an AdMob in an app as follows.
[image]

I applied AdMob native ad express in my app as follows.
[image]

I think the former is simpler and has a bigger button for install. What's it called?
It seems to work as a native ad since it's included in feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It simply looks like a template difference.

The first `adview` is the *medium* template and the second is the *small*  template.

**What is template?**

When you create a native ad for mobile in [admob console](https://apps.admob.com)
It Basically, it supports 3 templates (`small, medium, large`) and you can customize it with `CSS`.

Developers or teams can select and implement a template of a size suitable for their own layout design.

For more information, see [admob guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-express).